# Как передать данные из iframe в родительское окно?

Tags: jquery, javascript, iframe

Привет, ребят! Пишут виджет под Samsung Bada. Нужно определить местоположение.

Стандартная ф-ция `navigator.geolocation` в виджете не поддерживается, в то время как на том же телефоне в браузере всё отлично определяется. Появилась идея открывать в виджете `iframe` окно, определять локацию и передавать данные в родительское окно (виджет).

Есть какие-то идеи, как можно передавать данные из `iframe` в родительское окно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если будете вызывать скрипт из iframe, то

```
window.top.document
```

отправит вас к объекту документа родительской странички. Если наоборот считывать из iframe

```
iframeObject.contentWindow
```

UPD: А дальше в зависимости от вашей структуры. Можно писать значения в свойство какому-то из созданных объектов в момент определения геолокации и считывать его из виджета по мере необходимости.